# How to move file pointer to begining of the file in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I am trying to read contents of one file in MFC, where the file consists of several character array data types.so while reading using

```
ar.ReadString(tempstringTitle1);
ar.ReadString(tempstrTitle2);
```

I am getting all character array string values in `tempstrtitle1` itself instead of dividing.

Here is how I am writing:

```
char tempstrTitle1[23]="xydcvf";
char tempstrTitle2[23]="asdlk"
ar.WriteString(tempstrTitle1);
ar.WriteString(tempstrTitle2);
```

so please let me know how can I get those strings separately in `tempstrTitle1`, `tempstrTitle2`;

also in MFC I am getting file pointer using syntax:

```
const CFile* cfptr = ar.GetFile();
```

and I want to move this pointer to beginning of the file but I am using `cfptr->SeekToBegin();` but I am geting error saying the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member functions `CFile::SeekToBegin();`

please let me know what mistake i am doing? Thanks for help

Comment: You probably want to write single lines as `ar.WriteString("xydcvf\n")`... Then you read it with `ReadString`. If there is no `\n` at the end then it will appear as one string, unless you keep track of string size. Aside from that, there is no MCVE so it's hard to say what problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadString` reads until the next `\n` or until the end of file. So you need to write the file like this:

```
char tempstrTitle1[] = "xydcvf";
char eol[] = "\n";
char tempstrTitle2[] = "asdlk"

ar.WriteString(tempstrTitle1);
ar.WriteString(eol);
ar.WriteString(tempstrTitle2);
```

For your second question:

```
const CFile* cfptr = ar.GetFile();
```

is wrong becaue you can't do much with a const CFile pointer. You just should drop the `const`:

```
CFile* cfptr = ar.GetFile();
```

Comment: @rajee you're welcome. Don't write "thank you" but upvote and/or accept the question. That's the way so say "thank you" on stackoverflow.